# Remove all hidden files

Tags: scripting, command, delete

Is there a command that will remove all the hidden files in a directory, including its subdirectories?

I need it to only remove the hidden files, not regular ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find yourstartingpath/ -name ".*" -type f -exec rm {} \; -print
```

-print is only if you need listing of them

example :

```
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ touch {a,b,c,a/1,a/2,b/2}/.hid
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ touch {a,b,c,a/1,a/2,b/2}/nothid
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── nothid
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── nothid
│   └── nothid
├── b
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── nothid
│   └── nothid
└── c
    └── nothid

6 directories, 6 files
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ find . -name ".*" -type f -exec rm {} \; -print
./b/.hid
./b/2/.hid
./a/1/.hid
./a/.hid
./a/2/.hid
./c/.hid
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── nothid
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── nothid
│   └── nothid
├── b
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── nothid
│   └── nothid
└── c
    └── nothid

6 directories, 6 files
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$
```

all nothid(den) files are kept intact

Please : Never start a for loop or a find ... exec rm command without taking a backup of datas first :)

Comment: Thanks. Also, if I just want to print and not remove, what is the modified command?

Comment: @BobtheBob: just `find -name '.*' -type f`